# How to clear cookies before login off AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, logout, angular-cookies

I am using  AngularJS v1.5.8

My AngularJS application has a logout button, when I click on the button does not log me out, instead, it brings me back to the home page.

If I inspect the home page and go to to... Application tab --> Storage --> Cookies --> http://localhost:8080

There is a cookie with name: JSESSIONID.  If I manually clear the cookie within the inspect window, then I can logout OK, when I click the logout button it takes me to the login page with a "logged out successfully" message.  That is what I want but I can't figure out how to clear that cookie before loggin out.

I have tried all the examples I can find on this site but does not clear it for me.  Any Ideas?

This is what I have

```
var application = angular.module('application',["ng","ngRoute","ngCookies", "ngResource", "ngSanitize","ngAnimate","ngTouch"]);


var contextCtrl = application.controller('contextCtrl', [ '$location', '$rootScope', '$scope', '$contextService', '$timeout', '$cookies',
function($location, $rootScope, $scope, $contextService, $timeout, $cookies) {

    $rootScope.logout = function() {
        console.log('I am here...')
        $cookies.remove('JSESSIOINID');
        console.log('I am here again...')       
        $('#logoutForm').submit();
    }
```

Comment: What is the domain of the cookie? Is the Java API also running localhost? Also note, the Java API can set a cookie, so it's possible it's getting set back right after you delete it.

Comment: @jheimbouch I am pretty new to AngularJS this appwas given to me to continue development and don't know much about it.  How can I find out if the Java API also running localhost?  How do I findout the domain of the cookie?